# External Harddrive Permissions Changed / No Access

Tags: macos, hard-drive, external-disk, permission

my external harddrive permissions have suddenly changed.  I am getting mount errors in Disk Utility when I try to verify the disk.  When I Get Info for the drive in question, it states that I have "NO ACCESS", along with SYSTEM, ADMIN, and EVERYONE.  There is an EVERYONE at the top that has "custom access."  If I try to edit or add permisions for myself, it won't let me.

```
Last login: Tue Sep  1 16:17:55 on ttys000
Laurens-MacBook-Pro:~ LCLindley$ ls -AOel /Volumes
total 24
-rw-r--r--@ 1 LCLindley  admin  - 6148 Sep  1 16:28 .DS_Store
d--x--x--x+ 3 root       admin  -  102 Sep  1 12:12 Little Travel Buddy
 0: group:everyone inherited deny add_file,add_subdirectory,directory_inherit
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root       admin  -    1 Aug 21 10:26 Macintosh HD -> /
Laurens-MacBook-Pro:~ LCLindley$
```

I've found a bit of steps that may be helpful in this situation, but I'm hesitant to go screwing around in there without sepcifics to my situation/drive.  I downloaded Batchmod to try to fix it that way, but I can't see the drive in question in the files window and I can't seem to name it correctly to help it find it.  Thanks in advance for the help!  Cheers, L

Comment: What are the permissions on `ls -AOel /Volumes/Little* | head -3` It could be Time Machine is locking things down. Also - what's `diskutil list`

Comment: What are the results of the command `mount`?

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use any apps to do this, just open the terminal.

Try taking ownership first:

`sudo chown -R LCLindley.admin /Volumes/Little\ Travel\ Buddy`

then try fixing permissions so you can actually read and write it:

`sudo chmod -R 755 /Volumes/Little\ Travel\ Buddy`